# Vb.Net : Assembly Load error

Tags: .net, vb.net, frameworks, .net-assembly

I am trying to run vb.net winforms application and its throwing "The given assembly or codebase was invalid error" and fusion log contains below information,

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (6/23/2015 @ 3:28:06 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\My Company\myapp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = MyDomain\user1
LOG: DisplayName = myapp.resources, Version=2.1.0.15741, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/My Company/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = myapp.exe
Calling assembly : myapp, Version=2.1.0.15741, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\My Company\myapp.exe.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/My Company/en/myapp.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/My Company/en/myapp.resources/myapp.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/My Company/en/myapp.resources.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/My Company/en/myapp.resources/myapp.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the necessary version of the .NET Framework installed on the machine?  If so, you may want to try reinstalling it.

Comment: @StevenDoggart.. but its throwing error while reading resources from dependent dll files.. So how does reinstalling .net 2.0 will fix this error?